# How to add objects with Entity Framework without its associated entity duplicated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models: a `Product` class, a `Category` class, a `Color` class and a `Size` class; each `Product` has a `Category`, `Color`, and `Size`.

Information is coming from a CSV file, so before I add products into the database I  do A LINQ Select distinct on category, color and a size and insert those into the appropriate tables with EF code first.

Until that point, there is no problem.

Then what I try to do, is I iterate through every line of the CSV file and for each product I get its category, its size and its color, and create the Instance object of each one of those.

```
  public void InsertProduct(Product product)
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                ICategoryDao categoryDao = new CategoryDao();
                IColorDao colorDao = new ColorDao();
                ISizeDao sizeDao = new SizeDao();

                var category = categoryDao.GetCategoryByName(product.Category.CategoryName);
                var color = colorDao.GetColorByName(product.Color.ColorName);
                var size = sizeDao.GetSizeByName(product.Size.SizeName);

                var categoryEntity = new CategoryEntity()
                {
                    Id = category.Id,
                    CategoryName = category.CategoryName
                };

                var colorEntity = new ColorEntity()
                {
                    Id = color.Id,
                    ColorName = color.ColorName
                };

                var sizeEntity = new SizeEntity()
                {
                    Id = size.Id,
                    SizeName = size.SizeName
                };

                ProductEntity productEntity = new ProductEntity();
                productEntity.ActionPrice = product.ActionPrice;
                productEntity.ArticleNumber = product.ArticleNumber;
                productEntity.Category = categoryEntity;
                productEntity.Color = colorEntity;
                productEntity.Size = sizeEntity;
                productEntity.DeliveryTime = product.DeliveryTime;
                productEntity.Description = product.Description;
                productEntity.Key = product.Key;
                productEntity.Price = product.Price;
                productEntity.ActionPrice = product.ActionPrice;
                productEntity.Q1 = product.Q1;


                //Had issues with mapper and navigation attributes
                //var entity = Mapper.Map<Product, ProductEntity>(product);
                context.ProductEntities.Add(productEntity);
                context.SaveChanges();

                // update business object with new id
                //product.Id = entity.Id;
            }
        }
```

Then on the save changes I got a UNIQUE KEY Exception, something expected because category name, color name and size name are unique keys on their own tables. (not on the product table itself).

How can I insert the Product without trying to Insert Categories, Colors and Sizes?

```
public class SizeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Index("SizeName", IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string SizeName { get; set; }
    }

public class ColorEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Index("ColorName", IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string ColorName { get; set; }
    }

public class CategoryEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Index("CategoryName", IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Please note that the ProductDao object gets a Product (from the business object layer), not actually a Product Entity (from data access layer), so thats why I do some kind of Manual Mapping(object instance creation) on that method, which is where something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch every entity from the database before assigning them to the product entity if you do not want to create duplicates, something like:

```
var categoryEntity = context.CategoryEntities.Find(category.Id);
if(categoryEntity == null)
{
    categoryEntity = new CategoryEntity()
    {
        Id = category.Id,
        CategoryName = category.CategoryName
    };
    context.CategoryEntities.Add(categoryEntity);
}

// same approach for other entities
```

Assuming each of those entities have `Id` as primary key, you need to add those entities to the context before invoking `Find` method.

What you have to know is that this approach is extremely inefficient if you try to execute bulk inserts. My advice is to execute `context.SaveChanges()` just once, and not after adding each single entity.